# Issue using event.preventDefault

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue where all of my code runs in the manner that I'd expect, but I can't seem to get the event.preventDefault() to stop the page from refreshing. Am I just miss using the syntax or should I use a different method to prevent a page refresh upon form submission.

```
export default function contact(props) {
    function sendEmail(event) {
        if (Name !== "" || Email !== "" || Message !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();

        emailjs.sendForm("service_5xus7sn", "template_aqto6xc", event.target, "user_XmVRJ4snvOeb3UJlvluDS")
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text); window.location.reload()
        }).catch(error => console.log("You have an error in user message submit" , error))
    } else (
        () => setErrorMessage("You must fill in each field before submitting.")
    )
}
const [ErrorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")
const [Name, setName] = useState("")
const [Email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [Message, setMessage] = useState("")

return (
    <div className="contact-wrapper">
      <form className="form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
          <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="FullName" placeholder="Your name" onChange={() => setName(event.target.value)}/>
                <label htmlFor="FullName">Your name</label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" onChange={() => setEmail(event.target.value)}/>
                <label htmlFor="email">Your email</label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" onChange={() => setMessage(event.target.value)}></textarea>
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
          </div>

          <div className="spacer10"></div>

            <div className="error-message">
                <h3>{ErrorMessage}</h3>
            </div>

          <div className="centered-btn-wrapper">
              <button type="submit" className="btn" value="Send">Send</button>
          </div>
            
          <div className="spacer10"></div>
          <div className="spacer10"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: typically when I use event prevent default it is the first item in the function, and then I perform my validation.  if validation passes, I then manually submit the form element or reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  event.preventDefault();
  if (Name !== "" || Email !== "" || Message !== "") {
```

Move event.preventDefault() before if statement. For each situation it should be called.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue.